# Why does a corrupt MongoDB document cause an exception that mentions Transient fields on a DAO?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with a Spring Boot application that uses a Mongo database. The DB features a collection of documents MyDoc that has the following structure

```
{
"_id": "blahblahblah",
"_class": "com.mypackage.MyDoc",
"meaningfulField1": "something useful",
"meaningfulField2": "something else useful"
}
```

It has a Spring Data DAO object with the following class

```
package com.mypackage;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "MyDoc")
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
public class MyDoc {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String meaningfulField1;
    private String meaningfulField2;
    @Transient
    private Long someTransientValueThatIsDeterminedOnApplicationStartup;
}
```

There is a repository class that performs queries on this collection

```
package com.package.dao;

import com.package.MyDoc;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public interface MyDocRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDoc, String> {
    List<MyDoc> findAllByMeaningfulField1Exists(boolean exists);
}
```

The problem is that there is a document in the collection that only has an "_id" field

```
{
"_id": "blahblahblah"
}
```

This document is causing the `findAllByMeaningfulField1Exists()` method to throw an exception whenever it is called. Removing the document from the database has solved the problem and I think at root it's because this document doesn't have a "_class" attribute. But I'm curious about the messaging in the exception:

```
org.springframework.data.MappingException: No property someTransientValueThatIsDeterminedOnApplicationStartup found on entity class com.package.MyDoc to bind constructor parameter to
```

Why does the exception highlight the Transient field as being the problem when there are non-Transient fields that are also missing from that corrupt document?